# Setting a variable within a foreach statement?

Tags: c#, razor

I'd like to set a value from my foreach statement to a variable so that I can then parse that value.  My code looks as follows:

```
 @foreach (var visit in visitslist){
 CultureInfo MyCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
 var MyString = (visit.VisitDate);
 DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString, MyCultureInfo);

 <input type="text" value="@MyDateTime" />}
```

The trouble I'm having is that it's not pulling the value of visit.VisitDate through.  I've tried manually inputting a value from the database and that worked perfectly so I know it's not an issue with the data type.

Comment: You are overriding the var MyString each time in foreach loop. `string MyString = item.DateAdded`? So always the last value of item.DateAdded will set to MyString. Why it is defined in foreach loop? s that correct? should the MyString defined at locally in method body or a member variable?

Comment: is it throwing an error? Looks to me you're trying to assign a DateTime value to a string type.

Comment: I would like MyString to be the value from the table I'm pulling the data from for the foreach loop

Comment: what is the type of DateAdded?

Comment: @user1672994 from what you've mentioned I don't think this will actually work.  Basically, I need to parse the value of a datetime field so it appears in UK format as opposed to US.  Full code above.

Comment: is VisitDate stored as DateTime in DB or as string? If string, then you can use the DateTime.ParseExtract method to parse the provided string in the appropriate format to change the string to DateTime then convert back the DateTime in desired format.

Comment: @user1672994 it's stored as datetime in DB and it needs to stay like that as I use it elsewhere to bring values through to a calendar

Comment: Why do you need to parse in different culture if type of DateTime? Is your application specific to en-GB then you can set the Current thread culture as  ` Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");` so when you use `<input type="text" value="@MyDateTime" />` in your view it will show in en-GB format automatically.

Comment: @user1672994  that's worked!  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to parse the object in different culture if type of var is DateTime. If your application is specific to en-GB culture then you can set the Current thread culture as `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");`. So when you use `<input type="text" value="@MyDateTime" />` in your view it will show in the value in en-GB format automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in UK time, you just need to change its format by parsing it first then printing it with new format

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, though I get an error to say it's not a valid datetime